# removing a specific number of pallets from a pallet rack

Tags: anylogic

i would like to pick a certain amount of pallets from my racks but I have no idea how to actually do that. For example, I would like to deliver 5 pallets but i have 25 stored, if i use a wait or a queue that I release all agents get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

to release 5 agents from the wait block so they can be delivered you have to do the following

```
List <MyAgent> deliverables=findAll(waitBlock,w->true).subList(0,5);
for(MyAgent x : deliverables){
     waitBlock.free(x);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help ! That's what i ended up doing. However I'd like to specify to anyone who might stumble upon this lates is that you can't execute this like in any block. I had to create a function and call the function in the block for it to actualy work.